# Equivalent of route53 routing policy in Azure

Tags: azure, azure-traffic-manager, azure-dns

In aws Route53 supports Multivalue answer routing policy in much multiple A records can be added for same dns record.What is the equivalent of this in azure? I have opened azure dns service but I can't find any routing policy here. So is there a way in which I could configure my A records in round robin fashion(Multple ips for same dns record).

Answer (score 1):

This feature actually lies with [Azure Traffic Manager](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/services/traffic-manager/), and not Azure DNS.

Azure Traffic Manager supports six traffic-routing methods to determine how to route network traffic to the various service endpoints. The traffic-routing method determines which endpoint is returned in the DNS response. One of these is the [Multivalue](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/traffic-manager/traffic-manager-routing-methods#multivalue) traffic-routing method.

The **Multivalue** traffic-routing method allows you to get multiple healthy endpoints in a single DNS query response. This enables the caller to do client-side retries with other endpoints in the event of a returned endpoint being unresponsive. This pattern can increase the availability of a service and reduce the latency associated with a new DNS query to obtain a healthy endpoint.

Multivalue routing method works only if all the endpoints of type ‘External’ and are specified as IPv4 or IPv6 addresses. When a query is received for this profile, all healthy endpoints are returned and are subject to a configurable maximum return count.

More details can be found here: [Azure Traffic Manager routing methods](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/traffic-manager/traffic-manager-routing-methods)